# MVC5: Foreign Key and data access

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, foreign-keys

I am looking for selecting a list from my table based on another table. I need to retrieve system names that are part of a particular system family. i have already added foreign keys. I created a ViewModel containing both these classes but it throws a null pointer exception. I am new to MVC and I am not sure where I am wrong.

Model Class : Systems
 public class Systems
    {

```
    public int SystemsID { get; set; }
    public string SystemName { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set;}
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public int SystemFamilyID { get; set; }

    public virtual SystemFamily SystemFamily { get; set; }
}
```

Class SystemFamily

```
  public class SystemFamily
{

    public int SystemFamilyID { get; set;}
    public int SystemsID {get;set;}
    public string FamilyName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Systems> Systems { get; set; }


 }
```

ViewSystem is a method in my SystemFamilyController.

```
   public ActionResult ViewSystem(int? id)
    {
        var viewmodel = new Sys_SysFam();
        ViewBag.SystemFamilyID = id.Value;
        //if (id != null)
        //{
        //    ViewBag.SystemFamilyID = id.Value;
        //    viewmodel.Systems = viewmodel.SystemFamily.Where(
        //        i => i.SystemFamilyID == id.Value).Single().Systems;
        //}

        return View(viewmodel);
    }
```

the view :

```
@model SystemFam_System.ViewModel.Sys_SysFam
@{
ViewBag.Title = "ViewSystem";
 }

 <h2>ViewSystem</h2>

 <p>@ViewBag.SystemFamilyID</p>
 <table>
 @foreach (var item in Model.Systems)
 {
    string selectedRow = "";
    if (item.SystemFamilyID == ViewBag.SystemFamilyID)
    {
        //{
        //    selectedRow = "success";
        //}

        <tr class="@selectedRow">
            <td>
                @item.SystemName
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.SystemsID
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.SystemFamily
            </td>
        </tr>

      }
  }
</table>
```

I get null pointer Exception. I want to view the system that belongs to a particular family in view system.

Thanks in advance!!
Vini

Edit :

```
public class Sys_SysFam
{
    public IEnumerable<Systems> Systems { get; set; }
    public SystemFamily SystemFamily { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i have checked Sys_SysFam class too. As per your current code it will always throw null reference exception becasue in your controller code you are using:

```
public ActionResult ViewSystem(int? id)
    {
        var viewmodel = new Sys_SysFam();
        ViewBag.SystemFamilyID = id.Value;
        //if (id != null)
        //{
        //    ViewBag.SystemFamilyID = id.Value;
        //    viewmodel.Systems = viewmodel.SystemFamily.Where(
        //        i => i.SystemFamilyID == id.Value).Single().Systems;
        //}

        return View(viewmodel);
    }
```

here you are creating an object of Sys_SysFam as viewmodel and as your if part is commented so you are returning same viewmodel in which viewmodel.Systems will always be null. Here i did not see any request to database for getting the data from db but i think your data in viewmodel will come from database and if i uncomment your if condition then too you are not sending any request to database you are using same viewmodel object created above.

```
viewmodel.Systems = viewmodel.SystemFamily.Where(
                    i => i.SystemFamilyID == id.Value).Single().Systems;
```

in right side you are using viewmodel.SystemFamily with where condition but as viewmodel.SystemFamily is null it will always throw exception. Your solution should be something like this:

```
public ActionResult ViewSystem(int? id)
        {
            DataContext context = new DataContext();
            var viewmodel = new Sys_SysFam();
            ViewBag.SystemFamilyID = id.Value;
            if (id != null)
            {
                ViewBag.SystemFamilyID = id.Value;
                var sysFamily = context.SystemFamily.Include(x => x.Systems).FirstOrDefault(x => x.SystemFamilyID == id.Value);
                if (sysFamily != null)
                {
                    viewmodel.Systems = sysFamily.Systems;
                }
            }

            return View(viewmodel);
        }
```

here first i am creating object of DataContext which is my main context to access the database using entity framework. so first i will get the system family based on passed id from database and if system family is not null then i will set the data of systems in viewmodel. Include method will bring data for Systems based on system family from database.

Also improve your Sys_SysFam class to initialize systems so that it will not throw exception in your view when there is no data in viewmodel.Systems like this:

```
public class Sys_SysFam
    {
        public Sys_SysFam()
        {
            this.Systems = new List<Systems>();
        }

        public SystemFamily SystemFamily { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<Systems> Systems { get; set; }
    }
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i am unable to resolve _DataContext_

Comment: Are you using entity framework orm for database operations or Ado.Net?

Comment: DataContext i have used to query the database for getting the data

Comment: Ok I got it! The data context is context that i have made to create the database. In my program it is SystemsContext. I have resolved it. And it works.. Is my way of doing the task also right?

Answer (score 0):

```
Remove SystemsID property from SystemFamily class because it is not used for ICollection virtual property. so your SystemFamily class should be like this:

  public class SystemFamily
{

    public int SystemFamilyID { get; set;}
    public string FamilyName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Systems> Systems { get; set; }
 }
```

Comment: can you please update your question with Sys_SysFam class too

Comment: Something more that i could understand is that in my Viewsystem, the Sys_SysFam class contains null values. It doesnt take any values from the database. How can i handle it?

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine could find me a way. But it doesnt use any ViewModel. I would like to know how it need to be done with ViewModel as well..

```
        public ActionResult ViewSystem(int? id)
        {

            var model = from item in db.Systems
                        orderby item.SystemsID
                        where item.SystemFamilyID == id
                        select item;
            return View(model);
        }
```